# Custom Json parser unable to process the string value for the key

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to write my own JSON parser code but it is throwing error.
I notice following issues for the sample JSON code:  `{"name":"John","age": 30}`

-> My code is unable to read the string value `Jhon`
-> It is always taking numeric value along with `}` with value `30`

below is my code for the JSON parser:

```
function customJSONParse(jsonString){
    const sanitizedString = jsonString.replace(/\s/g, '');

    if(sanitizedString[0]==='{'){
        return parseObject(sanitizedString);
    }else if(sanitizedString[0]==='['){
        return parseArray(sanitizedString);
    }else{
        throw new SyntaxError('Unexpected token');
    }
}

function parseObject(jsonString){
    const object={};
    let key;
    let value;
    let startIndex=1;
    while(jsonString[startIndex]!=='}'){
        const colonIndex= jsonString.indexOf(':',startIndex);
        key=jsonString.substring(startIndex,colonIndex).replace(/"/g,'');
        const commaIndex=jsonString.indexOf(',',colonIndex);

        const valueString = jsonString.slice(colonIndex+1,commaIndex!==-1?colonIndex:undefined);
        value= parseValue(valueString); 
        object[key]=value;
        startIndex=commaIndex!=-1?commaIndex+1:jsonString.length-1;
    }
    return object;
}

function parseValue(valueString){
    if(valueString==='true'){
        return true;
    }else if(valueString==='false'){
        return false;
    }else if(valueString==='null'){
        return null;
    }
    else if(!isNaN(valueString)){
        return parseFloat(valueString);    
    } 
    else if(valueString[0]==='"'){
        return valueString.slice(1,-1);
    }
    else{
        throw new SyntaxError('Unexpected Token');
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me to fix the logical issue in my code?

Comment: You want to say `commaIndex!==-1?commaIndex:undefined`, right?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen yes

Comment: You probably want `jsonString.slice(colonIndex + 1, commaIndex);`, setting the 2nd argument to `undefined` like you're doing currently will make it take the rest of the string which will include the `}`, so you'll end up with `30}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the object by comma and parse the keys and values. In the example below we support parsing flat JSONs and we assume colon, comma and curly braces are not inside the values. More custom JSONs are not supported by this one, because here I'm only sharing a proof-of-concept.

```js
function customJSONParse(jsonString){
    const sanitizedString = jsonString.replace(/\s/g, '');

    if(sanitizedString[0]==='{'){
        return parseObject(sanitizedString);
    }else if(sanitizedString[0]==='['){
        return parseArray(sanitizedString);
    }else{
        throw new SyntaxError('Unexpected token');
    }
}

function parseObject(jsonString){
    let splitted = jsonString.substring(1, jsonString.length - 1).split(",").map(item => {return {key: item.substring(0, item.indexOf(":")), value: item.substring(item.indexOf(":") + 1)}});
    let obj = {};
    for (let item of splitted) {
        obj[item.key] = item.value;
    }
    return obj;
}

function parseValue(valueString){
    if(valueString==='true'){
        return true;
    }else if(valueString==='false'){
        return false;
    }else if(valueString==='null'){
        return null;
    }
    else if(!isNaN(valueString)){
        return parseFloat(valueString);    
    } 
    else if(valueString[0]==='"'){
        return valueString.slice(1,-1);
    }
    else{
        throw new SyntaxError('Unexpected Token');
    }

}
console.log(parseObject(`{"name":"John","age": 30}`))
```